# Variable name to be assigned as argument in a python function

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I am writing a function that builds and populates a tree-like data structure, using the `treelib` library. You create a tree as follows:

```
foo = Tree()
```

...and go from there, which is standard enough. Here is what I have, simplified:

```
def make_special_tree(tree, arg1, arg2):
    tree = Tree()
    other_stuff = things(arg1)
    modify_tree(tree, other_stuff, arg2)
    return tree
```

Here's the thing: let's say that I ultimately want a tree object called `blah`. If I do the following, the command runs without an error:

```
make_special_tree('blah', foo, bar)
```

...but when I type `blah` afterward, I get back `NameError: name 'blah' is not defined`. If I do the following, the command also runs without an error:

```
blah = make_special_tree('yoink', foo, bar)
```

...and when I type `blah` afterward, I get back `<treelib.tree.Tree object at 0x10e60db10>`, which is what I want to see. `yoink` meanwhile remains undefined, like `blah` in the previous version.

Hence my question--and I can tell this is basic, but I cannot untangle this, in part because I am not sure how precisely to ask the question. As you can see, right now I have to create an instance of class Tree() and I *think* I have to feed my function an argument to do so. I think that `blah = make_special_tree(args)` is the correct way to format this, but how can I pass the variable `blah` as the name of the tree structure I'd like returned?

Comment: You're creating the Tree object within the function. So don't pass it to it, simply remove the first argument. Then `blah = make_special_tree(foo, bar)` will work.

Comment: Values don't have names. You can have multiple variables all referring to the same value—or things that aren't even variables, like the individual elements of a list. Of course you can give a value a `name` attribute, or anything else you want, but that has nothing to do with what variables (if any) you're going to store it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python functions generally don't "assign variable names", they just return values, and you can do whatever you want with those values.

A value doesn't have a variable name.<sup>*</sup> Because a value can be stored in five different variables, or it can be stored in things that aren't variables, like the elements of a list. It doesn't care.

So, what you almost certainly want to do is what @spectras suggested in a comment: Get rid of that first parameter, and then store the value in whatever variable you want:

```
def make_special_tree(arg1, arg2):
    tree = Tree()
    other_stuff = things(arg1)
    modify_tree(tree, other_stuff, arg2)
    return tree

# Two different trees with different names
blah = make_special_tree(foo, bar)
yoink = make_special_tree(foo, bar)

# One tree with two names
spam = make_special_tree(foo, bar)
eggs = spam

# A tree with no names at all
cheese = []
cheese.append(make_special_tree(foo, bar))
```

---

If you really do want to create a global variable with a specified name, you can do that,<sup>**</sup> but it's a really bad idea, unless you're trying to do something unusual, like the way `collections.namedtuple` acts like a `class` statement.

---

<sub>* A value can have a name by having, e.g., a `name` attribute. You can even change the definition of the `Tree` class to use that `name` attribute as part of its output representation. But this still has nothing to do with what variables you store it in.</sub>

<sub>** The least hacky way is `globals()[name] = value`.</sub>

Comment: I *absolutely* did not want to create a global variable. (The horror, the horror!) Indeed the solution, obvious in retrospect, was to remove the first parameter. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @JPFerguson Many people don't realize it, but `make_special_tree` function is a global variable, as are any modules you import, and the `blah` that you assign the result to in module-level code, and so on. "Don't use globals" as a dogma doesn't quite work the same way in Python as in other languages. It's usually obvious when you're violating the spirit of it, but trying to come up with a rule that actually works for the letter of it, that's a different story…

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in your function is redundant. Try this:

```
def make_special_tree(arg1, arg2):
    tree = Tree()
    other_stuff = things(arg1)
    modify_tree(tree, other_stuff, arg2)
    return tree

blah = make_special_tree(foo, bar)
```

Comment: Yup, that’s the basic mistake I was making. Holdover from playing around with this library interactively, then trying to wrap things into a function. Thank you for the fast reply.